# Security concerns calling an ASP.NET WebAPI from both the client and controller in an MVC app

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API application that is separate from my ASP.NET Core MVC application (UI). I didn't want to combine them for several reasons since in the future many different clients might need to access the API.

The MVC application makes calls to the API two different ways:
1. Using System.Net.HttpClient in the MVC controllers to populate the View Models.
2. When making jQuery AJAX calls I figured it would be best to directly call the API. (Note: I enabled CORS to allow calls from the MVC application). This would be the same thing as an Angular client making calls directly to the API.

**My questions:**
Is what I am doing pretty common making calls to the API directly from the client with jQuery and additionally System.Net.HttpClient in the Controllers when not using AJAX and just loading the view data. Should the AJAX calls go to the MVC controller first then let them MVC controller make a DELETE request using System.Net.HttpClient so I am never directly calling the API from the client?

What would the security concerns be? I am a bit nervous calling the API directly from jQuery. I feel like anyone can pretent they are localhost:6000 (my MVC port) and make a DELETE request to localhost:6001/api/users/1 (my API port).

Comment: You can use token base authentication. Generally secure you controller. stop annoymous request .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely correct to be concerned about this. You should be securing your application from this making sure any requests to access these API methods are authorized.

I recommend reading [10 Points to Secure Your ASP.NET MVC Applications.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1116318/Points-to-Secure-Your-ASP-NET-MVC-Applicationshttp://) for an overview on how to protect your application from this kind of attack and several other common security vulnerabilities.